# MySQL Node JS: select query results to array and use this array in other functions

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I need to get user information and use it in all file but when i save it to array or session array - it show undefined.

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? AND password = ?', [login, login, password], function (err, results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.username = results[0].username;
                req.session.email = results[0].email;
                req.session.password = results[0].password;
                req.session.premium = results[0].premium;
                req.session.created_at = results[0].created_at;
            } else {
                console.log("Error!");
            }
        });
```

The arrays and sessions are always undefined...

Comment: where is `req` coming from? It usually means the `request` object and there's often a corresponding `res` object which you use to put results. You seem to be adding results to the request which seems the wrong place but it's hard to tell from this code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning im just need to use the results info in full file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

req is a function variable/public variable I assume.  connection.query is asynchronous.  Callbacks are always asynchronous, and every REST API is.

Asynchronous basically allows the function callbacks to run together with the next lines of code.

The reason why req isn't being returned any value is because the req's value gets printed out first before it's actually being assigned within the function.
If you would like to add everything to req, either do sth like:

```
someFunctionYouHaveCreated: (req,res,type) => {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? AND password = ?', [login, login, password], function (err, results) {

        if (results.length > 0) {
            req.session.username = results[0].username;
            req.session.email = results[0].email;
            req.session.password = results[0].password;
            req.session.premium = results[0].premium;
            req.session.created_at = results[0].created_at;
        } else {
            console.log("Error!");
        }

        DoSomething(req);
    });
}

DoSomething: (req) => {
  //Do something
}
```

Or, create a promise, and run the function based on promise.  Use promise.all to assign value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all, but I don't think you need such level of complexity.